# Migrate Sonarqube to support Java 17

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, sonarlint, java-17

I have some inconsistent warnings and code smells when scanning the code written with Java 17 LTS, below some warnings :

- When I migrate my classes to record, I see my imports tagged as unused within the code (**Remove this unused import 'java.util.List'**)

I'm wondering if I need to upgrade the sonarqube version (currently, I'm in tag: 8.9.5-developer) to version 9.3, will this save my issues ?
Anyone have already faced these issues ?

Thanx

Comment: According to https://community.sonarsource.com/t/will-java-16-and-17-be-supported-in-sonarqube-8-9-lts/47535 Java 17 is only supported in the 9.x versions. And if you read the announcement for [Sonarqube 9.3](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-9-3/) it seems that you need version 9.3.

Comment: This most probably will also make coverage reports not be generated